What statistical tests can I use in R to ascertain the statistical significance of clusters obtained using DIANA (DIvisive ANAlysis Clustering)?
I have a data set of cuticular hydrocarbons (CHCs) from 60 samples of aphids collected across mid, early and late activity season on three different plants species that they fed on. The CHCs can differ due to season or the plant they fed on or due to many different abiotic factors. I want to use DIANA to visualise the data. I found a similar analysis online where this has been done using R:
chcmain <- read.csv("chcsitobion.csv", header = TRUE)
row.names(chcmain) <- chcmain$X
chcmain <- chcmain[,2:18]

#Log transform data
chc_matrixmain <- log(data.matrix(chcmain))

#Compute divisive hierarchical clustering
hc_d <- diana(chc_matrix)

#Divise coefficient; amount of clustering structure found
hc_d$dc

#Plot dendrogram
pltree(hc_d, cex = 0.6, hang = -1, main = "Dendrogram of diana")

#Cut diana()tree into 4 groups
clust <- cutree(as.hclust(hc_d), k=4)

#Visualize the result in a scatter plot
fviz_cluster(list(data = chc_matrix, cluster = clust))

#Visualize clusters inside dendogram
pltree(hc_d, hang=-1, cex = 0.6)
rect.hclust(hc_d, k =4, border = 2:10)

I don't really understand how they have arrived at 4 clusters and if I can do any statistics to ensure that the clusters obtained are statistically distinct from each other.
Could you please guide me about how to decide the number of clusters and what stats I can do to support my analysis if I use DIANA?
It is not possible for me to have an a priori hypothesis about how many clusters to expect or to test a specific hypothesis because my data could be affected by multiple factors.
The scatterplot shows two principal components but I can't understand if this has been created using the first two PCs or all of them.
The code above is working for me but the steps about how they decided on 4 clusters and what statistical tests should be done to support the results is missing and I don't know enough to be sure of how I can use this analysis for my own data.

You could resample your data and repeatedly perform clustering. If not the same entities end up paired in the clusters, then the clustering seems instable.

Thanks @ Ggjj11 ! Would you have a links for how to do this in R? And how I could report the results?

I have no experience or expertise with this particular method or the software. But in my experience when people show two PCs they choose the first two PCs unless they explain otherwise.
